# How can I use trigger to avoid 6 minutes execution time limitation in google app script for the function which pass parameter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy multiple files from the original folder to a new folder on google drive based on users’ search parameters. The files could be many and there are cases I couldn’t finish copying  the whole files within 6 minutes. I tried to use trigger to re-run the function after 5 minutes. But the trigger couldn't work and I couldn't copy the file.

Would you help me, please ?

Html

```
<html>
    <form id="downloadpdf">
        <input id="urlclass" type="text" name="urlname"  />
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var urllink = [];     //this value assigned by another function. But let us assign statics variable as example urllink={“url1,url2,url3”}
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#downloadpdf").submit(function() { 
                $("#urlclass").val(urllink);

                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(retsearch){ 
                }).downloadthefile(this);
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

code.gs

```
function downloadthefile(urlpass){
var REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT=300000;
var MAX_RUNNING_TIME=360000;
var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var startRow= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_row');
      Logger.log("not in for loop =" + startRow);
var now=methodtimenow();
var dest_folde=DriveApp.createFolder(now);
var id = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dest_folde).next().getId();
var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("source id");
var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
var urlstring=urlpass.urlname;
var resultarray=urlstring.split(',');                //array of the return url from client side

for(var i=startRow; i < resultarray.length; i++){
var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  var fileurl=downloadfinalarray[i];
  var fileid=fileurl.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileid);
  var file2 =file.makeCopy(file.getName());
  dest_folder.addFile(file2);
  if(currTime - startTime >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME) {
      scriptProperties.setProperty("start_row", i);
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("downloadthefile")
               .timeBased()
               .at(new Date(currTime+REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT))
               .create();
      break;
    } else {
      Logger.log("nothing to do");
    }
}

return "good";
}
```

Comment: Are you manually resetting `start_row`? `var startRow= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_row');` looks suspect

Comment: You can call the Drive REST API directly from your client-side HTML. Once you move the file transfer operations to your client-side javascript you won't be bound by the 6-minute limit.

Comment: I didn't reset start_row manually? Do I need to reset it manually?  If I do where may I set it ? @   Spencer Easton

Comment: If there is example how to call Drive REST API in the client-side, would you share it please ? @ Dimu Designs

Comment: If you're working on over a potentially large collection of files, try using the [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) which is used to allow scripts to iterate collection of files. Also, use the `getContinuationToken()` method if processing an iterator in one execution would exceed the maximum execution time.